# Error while plotting pie-chart using Plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly, pie-chart

I have some real time twitter data and I am using these data to find the sentiment analysis. I write a code for sentiment analysis and got the accurate result, like these:

```
    senti_value Sentiment_type
1          0.00        Neutral
2         -0.75       Negative
3          0.00        Neutral
4         -0.25       Negative
5         -3.25       Negative
6         -0.35       Negative
7          0.35        Positve
8          1.75        Positve
9         -2.40       Negative
```

But when i am trying to plot sentiment_type column data as a percentage in pie chart i got an error. Here is my code:

```
p <- plot_ly(data, labels = ~Sentiment_type, values = ~as.character(Sentiment_type), type = 'pie') %>%
  layout(title = 'Sentiment Analysis',
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))
```

How can I plot `sentiment_type` column as a percentage in pie chart using `plotly` package in R, please suggest me.

Comment: Does [it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46236889/4836511) answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
data <- read.table(text="    senti_value Sentiment_type
1          0.00        Neutral
2         -0.75       Negative
3          0.00        Neutral
4         -0.25       Negative
5         -3.25       Negative
6         -0.35       Negative
7          0.35        Positve
8          1.75        Positve
9         -2.40       Negative", header=T)
data

p <- plot_ly(data %>% group_by(Sentiment_type) %>% 
               summarise(n=n()) %>% mutate(percent=n/sum(n)), 
             labels = ~Sentiment_type, values = ~percent, type = 'pie') %>%
  layout(title = 'Sentiment Analysis',
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))
p
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Yes, i am looking like this.

Comment: I am glad that it helped you. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I want one more suggestion from you, i am using syuzhet package in R to find the emotions of a tweet but this package find emotion for each word in a tweet. I want a emotion for each sentence not on a word. Is it possible to find it?

Comment: As it is not related to this question, please ask it as a new question and you will be getting suggestions in that thread.